# Grpc compilation for c++ with protobuf 2.6.1

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

We are not able to compile the grpc source code with protobuf version 2.6.1 on linux, when we try to compile with it states dependency on protobuf 3.0.0+. But we have our current code base existing with lower protobuf version, and we don’t want to upgrade to protobuf 3.0.0+ unless necessary for grpc compilation.

we are getting below error:
[MAKE]    Generating /home/harman/sample_code/grpc_client/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc++.pc
[MAKE]    Generating /home/harman/sample_code/grpc_client/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc++_unsecure.pc

DEPENDENCY ERROR

The target you are trying to run requires protobuf 3.0.0+
Your system doesn't have it, and neither does the third_party directory.

Please consult INSTALL to get more information.

If you need information about why these tests failed, run:

make run_dep_checks

Additionally, since you are in a git clone, you can download the
missing dependencies in third_party by running the following command:

git submodule update --init

Makefile:945: recipe for target 'stop' failed
make: *** [stop] Error 1

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I want compile grpc source code with protobuf version 2.6.1 installed on my linux machine.

Comment: without stating what specific error you recieve, no one knows whats wrong.

Comment: edited question to include compilation error message.